# I found a strange behavior in JS. How to stop this behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, function, undefined

let's start with two files index.html and script.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button>click me</button>
    <div></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
const buttonUser = document.querySelector("button");
const divUser = document.querySelector("div");

buttonUser.addEventListener("click", () => {
    divUser.innerHTML = `
        <h1> welcome to the page </h1> 
        <button onclick="welcomeMassage()"> click me 2 <button>
    `
})

function welcomeMassage() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
}
```

if i clicked in the first button the addEventListener work and adding h1 and second button two divUser adn if i click on the second one it's also work and console.log("Hello world") but :::::::

if change the javascript file  two script.mjs and index.js

```
    <script type="module" src="script.mjs"></script>
```

When I click on the first button, the addEventListener works, but when I click on the second button, it does not work and shows up in the console. The welcomeMassage function is not defined, and I can't access it from the console. So why has this happened, and how can I prevent this behavior?

i want when use scritp.mjs file and  i click in the button not show in console functionNamve not defined and perform the function

Comment: `welcomeMassage` needs to be "global" ... functions declared in `modules` do not get added to the global scope .... use something like `globalThis.welcomeMassage = function () {...etc` - Note: you don't need to use `.mjs` extensions for modules in browsers - that's a nodejs *hack* for dealing with mixing commonjs/esmodules - not saying don't do it, just that you don't need to - also, this is not *strange behaviour* - it is designed behaviour

Comment: so why it's designed like this ??

Comment: because that's how modules work - a different design would mean modules worked differently

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're facing is because of scoping. You need to ensure that welcomeMessage is accessible from the global scope so that your inline onclick handler can invoke it. One way to do this is by explicitly assigning the function to a property of the global window object. This makes the function accessible as a global variable, which allows it to be called from inline event handlers.

To fix this, here's the updated code:

In index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button>click me</button>
    <div></div>
    <script type="module" src="script.mjs"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In script.mjs

```
window.welcomeMessage = function() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
}

const buttonUser = document.querySelector("button");
const divUser = document.querySelector("div");

buttonUser.addEventListener("click", () => {
    divUser.innerHTML = `
        <h1> welcome to the page </h1> 
        <button onclick="welcomeMessage()"> click me 2 </button>
    `;
});

const buttonUser = document.querySelector("button");
const divUser = document.querySelector("div");

buttonUser.addEventListener("click", () => {
    divUser.innerHTML = `
        <h1> welcome to the page </h1> 
        <button onclick="welcomeMessage()"> click me 2 </button>
    `;
});
```

Comment: What did you change, besides moving the function to the top and fixing the typo (massage -> message)? This looks exactly the code that the OP has, and doesn't work.

Comment: Try now. welcomeMessage was not in scope. @Bergi